# how to use a custom calendar int he django backend?

Tags: django, django-admin, widget, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a Date of birth field in my admin form of my django app.
When a user has to select a date he must click back month by month. An old person has to click a lot (If born in 1970 and the calendar starts on 2011 for example).

Is there a way to select year by clicking on it? Or to load a difference calendar widget completely i.e. [jquery-calendar](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-changeYear)? How can I do either of these?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not happy with the default Django form widgets, any of the widgets, your recourse is to create your own or subclass and modify one of the existing. There's tons of posts online about this topic. As always, Google is your friend.

Specifically concerning jQuery Datepicker, I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1693916) (updated), which might be helpful to you.

Comment: The link has expired. Could post it again or another tutorial for this? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that blog has been wiped from the face of the earth (or at least Google). However, I was able to find a gist that is based on that article, but implements it as HTML5. It should be easy to change it back to HTML4/XHTML, but the Django admin in 1.4 is switching to HTML5, so it's probably not a bad idea to go this direction overall. (Link above has been updated)